# Diferentes clases para layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge

Tags: java, android

Tengo tres layout para cada actividad: layout, layout-large y layout-xlarge para poder adaptar mi aplicación a todas las pantallas, el problema viene que utilizo una listview personalizada con mi clase ListViewAdapter y su xml, pero las medidas del xml de mi ListViewAdapter no son las correctas en los tres layout (large, xlarge) por lo tanto necesito crear diferentes xml de mi ListViewAdapter, pero cómo hago para layout-large y xlarge carguen diferentes xml (de mi ListViewAdapter)?
Espero que se entienda mi pregunta

Dejo por aquí mi ListViewAdapter:

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] titulos;
    int[] imagenes;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] titulos, int[] imagenes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.titulos = titulos;
        this.imagenes = imagenes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titulos.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imgImg;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_title);
        imgImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_image);

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtTitle.setText(titulos[position]);
        imgImg.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

mi clase:

```
public class cat_recetas extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListViewAdapter adapter;

    String[] titulo = new String[]{
            "Top 15",
    };

    int[] imagenes = {
            R.drawable.icon_top_15,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cat_recetas);

        final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_rec);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, titulo, imagenes);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {
                switch (posicion) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent top15 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), top15.class);
                        startActivity(top15);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Prueba agregar un archivo diferente según requieras en el folder de acuerdo a su densidad. Agregue una respuesta, comentame que resultados obtienes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cómo hago para layout-large y xlarge carguen diferentes xml (de mi
>   ListViewAdapter)?

Simplemente crea un archivo `list_row.xml` en cada folder, con esto el sistema operativo decidira cual tomar de acuerdo a su densidad.

```
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
```

---

Si ocupas medidas de dimensiones diferentes las cuales puedes definir dentro del archivo `dimens.xml` puedes definir un archivo con la medida correspondiente a su densidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado, no sé como no me di cuenta si ya estaba creándolo para los demás XML, gracias de nuevo @Elenasys !

Comment: Excelente que bien que resolviste tu mismo el problema, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ